# Different line endings in MSVC and g++

Tags: c++, parsing, visual-c++, g++

I'm trying to parse a text from file, in which I have to detect empty lines.
I'm running the code in 2 places:

- win 10, visual studio 2019(MSVC)
- under WSL, ubuntu 20.04, g++

Same computer, same file, same code.

```
while (getline(inputFile, line))
{
    if (line.length() == 1)
    {
        std::cout << "Empty line" << std::endl;
    }
/*blabla*/
```

With this code MSVC doesnt print empty lines, g++ does.

---

```
if (line.empty())
{
    std::cout << "Empty line" << std::endl;
}
```

With this code MSVC finds empty lines and g++ doesnt.

---

```
if (int(line[0]) == 10 || int(line[0]) == 13)
{
    std::cout << "Empty line" << std::endl;
}
```

With this code g++ finds empty lines, MSVC doesnt

1. Is it the Linux kernel that changes line endings or the compiler?
2. What is the proper way to always detect line endings and empty line on every system?

Comment: `\r`, `\n` can replace magic numbers 10,13.

Comment: The convention of line endings is OS-dependent. There is Windows convention (`\r\n`) and Unix convention (`\n`), and old-timers remember the classic (prior to OS X) Mac convention (`\r`). If you transfer text files between different operating systems, you need to either recode them using some kind of tool, or be prepared to parse different line endings in your program. Naturally a Unix program will see `\r` as a regular character rather than a part of a line-end sequence. It is your responsibility to discard it.

Comment: Note: Doing `line[0]` on an empty line makes the program have undefined behavior.

Comment: You may want to check the common `unix2dos` and `dos2unix` tools, which add or remove the `\r` before `\n`.

Answer (score 1):

Your difficulties stem from the fact that you're mixing Windows and Linux line endings on the same machine. WSL is a Linux-like environment, and processing Windows files on WSL is no different than processing them on a real Linux machine, i.e., problematic.

[`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) strips the `\n` (0x0A) line endings, and additionally in MSVC, reading a file in text mode automatically strips the `\r` (0x0D) characters. The latter does not happen on Linux.

So reading a Windows text file (with `\r\n` line endings) on a non-Windows platform will strip `\n` but leave `\r` at the end of the line.

If you want to handle that situation, you can strip the trailing `\r` manually. For example

```
while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
{
    if (!line.empty() && line.back() == '\r')
    {
        line.pop_back();
    }
    if (line.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Empty line" << std::endl;
    }
```

It is usually helpful to print out the `line` in binary mode when debugging, because `\r` and `\n` are invisible characters.